# Django - passing model object datas to template

Tags: python, django, templates

I could'nt solve it. I want to pass specific datas from model to template.
I had tried something could'nt figure it out.Can anyone help me out , should I need to write logic to view.py or is there easy way to pass data.

```
class Receipt(models.Model):

amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
vat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.total_amount)



#My view.py


class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"
    model = Receipt
class DetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "detail.html"
    model = ReceiptItem


#index.html

    <div class="panel panel-default">

  <div class="panel-heading">Market</div>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      {% for amount in objects %}
      <td>{{ amount }}</td>
      <td>{{ vat }}</td>
      <td>{{ total_amount }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TemplateView` does not provide support for models. If you want a list of all of the objects so you can loop over them you will want a `ListView`, then switch your for loop to be:

```
{% for amount in object_list %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

Comment: @KaanSan If that worked, can you mark this as an answer? Thanks!